# Laravel Eloquent is there a way to update Mysql json datatype key only?

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I have data in MySQL db, table 'user', column 'attributes' with json type as follow :

```
{"hp": {"remaining": 10, "total": 10}, "mp": {"remaining": 5, "total": 5}}
```

I want to update hp->remaining to 9 without updating the whole json but just the key

1st method :

```
$user = Users::find(1)->firstOrFail();
$user->attributes->hp->remaining = 9;
$user->save();
```

it failed saying Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Models\Users::$attributes has no effect

2nd method :

```
$user = Users::find(1)->firstOrFail();
$user->attributes = json_encode(array('hp' => array('remaining' => 9)));
$user->save();
```

it didn't have any errors but it failed because it updated the whole json attributes and lost 'hp->total' key and all mp, thus became

```
{"hp": {"remaining": 9}}
```

I know I can just replace the whole json with updated key like:

```
$user = Users::find(1)->firstOrFail();
$user->attributes = json_encode(array(
                                      'hp' => array('remaining' => 9, 'total' => 10), 
                                      'mp' => array('remaining' => 5, 'total' => 5)
                                     ));
$user->save();
```

However is there a way to update just the key?

Comment: decode the json string to an array and then update the query..

Comment: you can't. json is a container format, and should never be manipulated directly. decode a native structure, change any values you want, then re-encode to json. anything else risks corrupting the json.

Comment: not forget to choose approved answer by click on gray "check" on its left side

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '{"hp": {"remaining": 10, "total": 10}, "mp": {"remaining": 5, "total":      5}}';
$array=json_decode($str,true);
$array['hp']['remaining'] = 9;
$result = json_encode($array);
echo $result;
result is {"hp":{"remaining":9,"total":10},"mp":{"remaining":5,"total":5}}
hope use for you...
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work (laravel 5.5)

```
$data = $user->attributes;
$data['hp']['remaining'] = 9;
$user->attributes = $data;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = Users::find(1)->firstOrFail();

$decode = json_decode($user,true); //use as an array
$uid = $decode["id"];
$remaining = $decode["hp"]["remaining"];
$remaining1 = $decode["mp"]["remaining"];
$encode_remaining = json_encode($remaining);
$encode_remaining1 = json_encode($remaining1);

$db = User::where("id","=",$uid)->update([$encode_remaining=> 9 , $encode_reamaining1 => 5]);
```

Hope this helps!